# How to make view over recyclerview permanent example not scroll in nestedscrollview

Tags: android

Hi i want to make view not scroll able over recyclerview,for example a textview above recyclerview in nestedscrollview,how can i make textview not scrolling while recycler scroll as usual

my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="#43a047"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/app"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

how to make textview not scroll

Comment: why did you had to use nested scroll-view here?

Comment: then the toolbar doesnot scroll app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  ,even by putting it in relative view this is why

Comment: can you post an image to show what you want?

Comment: i want the textview not scrollabe CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbar scrollable

Answer (score 0):

You have the `TextView` inside the `NestedScrollView`. So your `TextView` scrolls because of that parent view. Something like that would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#43a047"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/app"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: then the toolbar doesnot scroll app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  ,even by putting it in relative view

Comment: I really cant understand what you want to do. Please post an image or something.

Answer (score 0):

The `RecyclerView` itself scrollable, so just remove the `NestedScrollView`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#43a047"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/app"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

Comment: then the toolbar doesnot scroll app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  ,even by putting it in relative view